# How travel sites lock room?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a hotel booking system  (PHP, MySQL) but I can't figure out the most efficient way to lock rooms (prevent the same room from being booked more than its allotment on the same date) for just 20 mins and release it if visitor doesnt make payment within that time. The system can grow large so I'd like to make sure that it's as efficient as it can be.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a simple time stamp field in the database to indicate"locked". Whenever someone attempts to book the room, the software compares the current time with the timestamp, and if it is > than 20 minutes and the payment has not been made, the lock is not valid.

This method is probably sufficiently efficient. A timestamp is usually 32-bits and the performance hit on the database calls with comparison negligible.